# Nutch possibilities

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, nutch

i am new to nutch and am using nutch 1.9. right now am doing some POC on a sample site(shaadi.com). I have few questions, can somebody help me out on this?

1. i cant access the urls that requires login authentication(**form based**), though i setup the configuration in httpclient-auth.xml, nutch-site.xml and all.
2. i know nutch fetches us only the whole content of the website. but is it possible to get only a piece of information like first name, address etc.. from the website page using nutch? (i think its more like scraping.. this is what pythons **scrapy** does)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use plugin to extract specific data & add that data to nutch document while indexing.
This plugin can be used to extract data
www.atlantbh.com/precise-data-extraction-with-apache-nutch/

Comment: Thanks Ganapat. i referred the url that mentioned and also able to get my issue fixed. Now my concern is totally on form based authentication. I followed all the steps that they mentioned in nutch-827 jira issue and also referred lifelongprogrammer blogspot, which is accomplished by @jayesh Bhoyar. But still i am unable to achieve form based authentication. do u have any idea about this?. thanks in advance..